# Remove comma (,) if the string ends with it using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to delete comma (,) if the string ends with it using replace methods. I don't want to use `endsWith`and delete the last character.

eg:

```
let str = 'KOP, Paoli,';
str = str.replace(/.*,$/, '');  // didn't work
str = str.replace(/^(.*,)$/, '');  // didn't work
```

Comment: `.replace(/,$/, '')` (single `,` at the end) or `.replace(/,+$/, '')` (all commas at the end of string)

Comment: **[It works well](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/J7VEobikSMFWQd3bP0BHISAxPydTR92aKzk/rzg/J1UvJz9dA6hAryi1ICcxOVVDX0dbRV9HQV1dU/P/fwA)**

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it works if it ends with comma (`,`), but not comma and space (`, `), I guess that's the problem

Comment: Not a problem at all, add `\s*` after `,+`. Or just `/\s*,[,\s]*$/`